# What does “typedef void *(*Something)(unsigned int)” mean

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

I am wondering, what does below mean
in .h, it has

```
 typedef void *(*some_name)(unsigned int);
```

And then in .c

```
some_name rt;
some_name State= 0;
unsigned int t = 1;
rt = (some_name) State(t);
```

Comment: Take a look at this: [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+*%28*some_name%29%28unsigned+int%29%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates an alias `some_name` for a pointer to a function with a return type `void*` and a single unsigned int parameter. An example:

```
typedef void *(*my_alloc_type)(unsigned int);

void *my_alloc(unsigned int size)
{
    return malloc(size);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    my_alloc_type allocator = my_alloc;
    void *p = allocator(100);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This typedef

```
typedef void *(*some_name)(unsigned int);
```

introduces an alias for pointer to a function of the type `void *( unsigned int )` that is that has the return type `void *` and one parameter of the type `unsigned int`.

As for this code snippet

```
some_name rt;
some_name State= 0;
unsigned int t = 1;
rt = (some_name) State(t);
```

then it does not make a sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef void *(*some_name)(unsigned int);
                ^^^^^^^^^
```

`somename` is

```
typedef void *(*some_name)(unsigned int);
              ^^         ^
```

a pointer

```
typedef void *(*some_name)(unsigned int);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to a function that accepts an unsigned int

```
typedef void *(*some_name)(unsigned int);
        ^^^^^^
```

and returns a pointer to void

```
typedef void *(*some_name)(unsigned int);
^^^^^^^
```

but for types.

---

So "the type `somename` is for functions that accept unsigned and return pointer to void"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef void *(*some_name)(unsigned int);
void *foo(unsigned t) {
    if (t == 0) return NULL;
    return malloc(t);
}
int main(void) {
    somename fxptr = foo;
    void *bar = fxptr(42);
    free(bar);
}
```